Running WebSockets on Azure Container Apps
I have deployed a WebSocket service to Azure Container Apps, seemingly without issues at first glance. The service seems to work perfectly from the point of view of the client.
However, when looking at the logs of the container, it seems to be full of the following errors which keep repeating non-stop.
opening handshake failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/websockets/http11.py", line 134, in parse
    request_line = yield from parse_line(read_line)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/websockets/http11.py", line 380, in parse_line
    line = yield from read_line(MAX_LINE_LENGTH)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/websockets/streams.py", line 46, in read_line
    raise EOFError(f"stream ends after {p} bytes, before end of line")
EOFError: stream ends after 0 bytes, before end of line

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/websockets/asyncio/server.py", line 353, in conn_handler
    await connection.handshake(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/websockets/asyncio/server.py", line 204, in handshake
    raise self.protocol.handshake_exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/websockets/server.py", line 551, in parse
    request = yield from Request.parse(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/websockets/http11.py", line 136, in parse
    raise EOFError("connection closed while reading HTTP request line") from exc
EOFError: connection closed while reading HTTP request line

This is not an issue when the container runs locally on my machine.
My guess is that Azure Container Apps automatically calls some endpoint which is not supported by my WebSocket server, but I haven't been able to figure out what exactly and why. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction as to what I could change.

please share the code in text format of  WebSocket service in the above question

After going through the documentation of Azure Container Apps, I found the solution here: Health probes in Azure Container Apps.
It seems like when no specific health probes are defined for a container app, the probes are automatically and silently defined for you, even if they are not visible when looking at the configuration of your container app.
These default probes are:



Probe type
Default values




Startup
Protocol: TCPPort: ingress target portTimeout: 3 secondsPeriod: 1 secondInitial delay: 1 secondSuccess threshold: 1Failure threshold: 240


Readiness
Protocol: TCPPort: ingress target portTimeout: 5 secondsPeriod: 5 secondsInitial delay: 3 secondsSuccess threshold: 1Failure threshold: 48


Liveness
Protocol: TCPPort: ingress target port



The issue here, is that the TCP request to the root path of the server will not work, and the liveness probe will never succeed.
The solution is simply to add support for a simple HTTP /health endpoint to the server, which returns a 200 response. Then, it's necessary to explicitly define a liveness probe for the container using HTTP protocol, this new endpoint, and the correct port.
The liveness probe is required, and cannot be ignored, but setting it up in this way, will ensure that the logs are not cluttered with errors.

The EOFError: EOF when reading a line error in Python occurs when the input() function attempts to read a line of input. For more details, refer to this documentation to resolve the EOF error.
Below are the steps to create and deploy WebSockets on Azure Container Apps:

Create a container registry and activate the Admin user.
In our project structure, make sure to create and activate a virtual environment in Python. Below is the structure of my project:

app.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS  

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")  


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(msg):
    print('Received message: ' + msg)
    socketio.emit('message', msg)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)



templates/index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flask WebSocket Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Flask WebSocket Example</h1>
    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Enter a message">
    <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>
    <p id="response"></p>

    <script>
       
        const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
        
   
        socket.on('message', (msg) => {
            console.log('Received message: ' + msg);
            document.getElementById('response').textContent = 'Received: ' + msg;
        });


        function sendMessage() {
            const message = document.getElementById('message').value;
            socket.emit('message', message);  
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>






requirements.txt:
 flask
Flask-SocketIO
flask-cors
eventlet
gunicorn

Docker:

FROM python:3.9-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 5000
#CMD ["python", "app.py"]
CMD ["gunicorn", "-k", "eventlet", "-w", "1", "app:app", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000"]


Build the image using:
docker build -t websocket-chat .

Then Tag the image to match the ACR repository format:
docker tag websocket-chat  AzureRegisterName.azurecr.io/websocket-chat:latest and
Login to your Azure Container Registry by below commmand:
az acr login -n 


Now, push the tagged image to your Azure Container Registry:
docker push AzureRegisterName.azurecr.io/websocket-chat:latest


If web app make sure turned on Web sockets option in Configuration > Web sockets > On. make sure the port 80 & 443.
Go to the Repositories section in Container registry , select the image, and click on Run instance.

Then you be loaded for creating Container .Enter the Container name, select Public IP address as Yes , and configure the port.

Use the IP address to browse your Container app.

